# How to get a variable value into jQuery / ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a variable into a jQuery function. I have found many other SO on it but I don't really understand how they would relate to my code or how the syntax works. I am new to JS so I am sure I just don't understand something.

Below I want to get the value of php_file_path_to_call[i] in my ajax call. It can be put in a variable before going into jQuery as it is just in a loop. Could you please show me exactly what the code would be to do this? I have been stuck for many hours! Thanks very much :)

```
    <script>
        tb_checkbox_value = 0
        tb_js_checkbox_id = '<?php echo $checkbox_id;?>';
        no_of_checkboxes_on_page = '<?php echo $no_of_checkboxes_on_page;?>';
        counter = '<?php echo $checkbox_counter;?>';    
        if (counter == 0){
            checkbox_element = [];
            php_file_path_to_call = [];
        //  alert("array created")
        }
        php_file_path_to_call[counter] = '<?php echo $php_file_path_to_call;?>';        
        js_user_id = '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
        temp_checkbox_element = document.getElementById(tb_js_checkbox_id)
        checkbox_element.push(temp_checkbox_element)
        if (counter == (no_of_checkboxes_on_page - 1)){  //outputs on last loop
            alert('if statement counter = ' + counter)
            for (i = 0; i <= (no_of_checkboxes_on_page - 1); i++) {
                alert('for statement counter = ' + i)
                jQuery(checkbox_element[i]).click(function(){       
                    if(jQuery(checkbox_element[i]).prop("checked") == true){
                        tb_checkbox_value = 1
                    }
                    else if(jQuery(checkbox_element[i]).prop("checked") == false){
                        tb_checkbox_value = 0
                    }
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: php_file_path_to_call[i],
                        data: {userid: js_user_id, checkbox: tb_checkbox_value},
                        success: function() {
                            alert("Success checkbox value: " + tb_checkbox_value + "file path: " + php_file_path_to_call[i])
                            jQuery('#tb-checkbox-saved').html('SAVED')
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                jQuery('#tb-checkbox-saved').html('')
                            }, 1333); 
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your ajax call already uses the value of `php_file_path_to_call[i]` as the url it calls. If you want it, in addition to that, as a value in your data object you simply add it to the `data` option. (`data: {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}` ...)

Comment: Thanks @Lapskaus. Currently the php_file_path_to_call[i] called by the ajax doesn't seem to work. So you're saying it should work?

To add it in addition then would be:
```
jQuery(checkbox_element[i]).click(function(data: {php_file_to_call: php_file_path_to_call[i] } ) {    

```
Would that be right?

Comment: @Lapskaus it currently gives filepath undefined...

Comment: I've realized it's because of the counter i...this isn't in the ajax function so that's why it returns undefined. If I put a 0 instead of i there is a value as you say there should be!